# MapReduce weird behavior

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a simple MongoDB MapReduce to count the active users in my database (see below).

For some reason it looks like the script is not fetching the whole database. I've got 400 records but it counts only 80 of them if I make the sum.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a limit of values per key? Any help welcome.

```js
db.user.mapReduce(
// map
function() {
        emit(this.state, {count: 1});
},

// reduce
function(key, val) {

    var counttotal = 0;
    var countActive = 0;

    for (var i in val) {
        data = val[i];

        counttotal++;

        // active state
        if (key == 1) {
            countActive++;
        }

    }

    return {
        countActive: countActive,
        counttotal: counttotal
    };

},

{
    out: {
        replace: "report"
    },
    query: {
        created_on: { $lt: new Date(2013, 8) }
    }
})
```

Comment: map reduce is batched to 101 results which means your reduce is actually returning the last batch results because of `    var counttotal = 0;
    var countActive = 0;` which is resetting your results

Comment: Thanks @Sammaye, that makes sense. How could I make a sum of those batches then, in the finalize?

Comment: You can use the results of the previous value to keep counting, you cna use the `+=` operator on the the vars to only set them 0 if they are etc etc

Comment: Thanks again @Sammaye you put me in the right direction and I solved my problem after days of questioning. I managed to fetch the whole DB following these instructions:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Restrictions_on_map_and_reduce_functions (in theory)
http://damienkatz.net/2008/02/incremental_map_1.html (in practice, add a 'break' statement in the switch, he forgot it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple Aggregation Framework pipeline which is officially recommended over map-reduce:

```
db.states.aggregate([
  {$match: {created_on: { $lt: new Date(2013, 8) }}},
  {$project: {state: 1, active: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$state", 1]}, 1, 0]}}},
  {$group: {_id : "$state", total: {$sum: 1}, totalActive: {$sum: "$active"}}}
  ])
```